# Кипеш или кипиш?

Tags: этимология, орфография, жаргон

Как следует писать это слово? И какое его происхождение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Кипеш* или *кипиш*?
>
> Как следует писать это слово? И какое его происхождение?

Это слово имеет множество написаний.

Из [**"Словаря русского арго"**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/argo/53_15286) на **Грамоте.ру**:

> **ХИПЕЖ**, -а, **ХИПЕС**, -а, **ХИПЕШ**, -а, **ХИПИЖ**, -а, **ХИПИС**, -а, **ХИПИШ**, -а, **КИПЕЖ**, -а, **ХИБЕЖ**, -а, **ХИБЕС**, -а, **ХИБЕШ**, -а, **ХИБИЖ**, -а, **ХИБИС**, -а, **ХИБИШ**, -а, м.
>
> Шум, скандал, крик. *хипеж поднять* (или *навести*) — поднять шум,
>   устроить кому-л. крупную головомойку.
>
> *Уг.* «хипе(и)ж(с)» — грабительство с помощью женщины-проститутки, заманивающей жертву, *ср.* «хипесник» — соучастник такого ограбления;
>   возм. связано с *уг.* «хипа» — женский половой орган, восходящим к
>   древнееврейскому chupo — балдахин, имеющий отношение к свадебному
>   обряду (chupe stl'ln — устроить свадьбу). *Уг.* «хипес», таким
>   образом, есть *мн.* от «хипа» (сhupo).

Наиболее нормативными из приведённых выше вариантов написания, видимо, следует считать   [***хипеж***](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B6) и [***кипеж***](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B6), зафиксированные в "Русском орфографическом словаре".

Comment: Гм. "ж" на конце для меня удивительно, хотя оно более соответствует русскому словообразованию. Чаще встречал с "ш" на конце, даже есть глагол "кипешить" ("кипешевать"?) в смысле "не кипешуй". Слово совершенно очевидно происходит из идиш, а там таки "ш/с" на конце.

Comment: Извините но "хупа" (еврейский свадебный балдахин) не имеет никакого отношения к "женскому органу". Это буквально и переводится как покрывало. "Хипесник" так же как "хипес" - от значения искать, обыскивать, в данном случае, наверно, обшаривать карманы. Никаких проституток.

Answer (score 2):

"Х'ипеш" действительно и совершенно очевидно происходит из идиш и означает обыск или облаву. Отсюда семантика паники и беспорядка. Может произноситься с **С** на конце: "хипес"(так даже ближе к оригиналу).
К хупе(свадебному причиндалу), хиппи, кипению и т.д. отношения не имеет.
**Ш** на конце имеет тенденцию переходить в **Ж**, видимо, по аналогии с "галдёж", "платёж" и т.д.(но это уже не имеет отношения к происхождению).

Answer (score 1):

Происходит из идиша, восходит к ивритскому "хипус", что означает поиск и обыск. Многие блатные слова родились в Одессе, и это просто факт, а не предмет гордости (хотя участнику с именем Нормальный этот факт не нравится; да и бороться за приоритеты в области блатной лексики вообще смешно).

Comment: Кипеш или кипиш?

Comment: @shampar Тут я не уверен. У меня на слуху кипиш, но это субъективное мнение. А авторы словарей не пришли к единому мнению.